What is the history of the Baptists, especially their early history and the separation of SBC?
I am looking for a scholar familiar with Baptist history to provide an introduction to the early history of the Baptists.  In particular, I want to learn about the founding and early development stages of the Baptist denominations, including an explanation of the situation when the Southern Baptists separated from the Northern Baptists in the USA.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange, Leon. This is an interesting subject so I've up-voted your question. However, I wondered if you have looked at older questions about Southern Baptists - you will see them listed in the Related column on the right-hand side of this screen.

This question/answer may be useful: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/what-do-southern-baptists-believe-about-predestination

This article gives an overview of the Southern Baptist Convention but does not provide a detailed history of the Baptists. https://www.gotquestions.org/Southern-Baptist-Convention.html

I hesitated to tackle your question because it is so vast in scope. The history of the Baptists goes back way before they were established on the North American continent, but I assume you know about that.
Here are some partial quotes from an article about the split between the Southern and the Northern Baptists:

The Southern Baptist Convention got its start in 1845 during the turmoil that led to the Civil War. As with the war itself, there were many factors that led to the division between North and South, but the headline issue for the church was slavery. Following the great revivals of the early 1800s, many Baptist churches in the northern states took a strong stand for the abolition of slavery. Though the Triennial Convention attempted to mediate the issue by establishing a non-committal policy on slavery, the southern churches felt slighted in the national meeting and formed their own convention at the First Baptist Church of Augusta, Georgia. Though they differed on the issue of slavery, the Southern Baptists and Northern Baptists essentially held the same doctrines following the split. One key distinction in practice was the cooperative movement in the Southern Baptist Convention. Whereas the Northern Baptists maintained their independence, the Southern Baptists formed a cooperative body to support world missions and other causes. These cooperative efforts were directed by the central administration rather than the churches.


Throughout their history, the Southern Baptists have seen the same kind of struggles with liberalism and modernism that many other churches have. From its founding, the Southern Baptist Convention was more concerned with functional unity than doctrinal unity, and, as a result, there was a wide divergence of beliefs within the churches of the denomination. In the 1950s liberalism began to increase in the seminaries, resulting in many students doubting the truthfulness of the Bible. In the 1963 convention, the Baptist Faith and Message was written to try to keep the peace between liberals and conservatives, but the schism continued to grow. Conservative members sought to uphold the Bible as the inspired, inerrant Word of God, which is authoritative in every area of life (2 Timothy 3:16). More liberal members questioned the historical accuracy of certain sections of Scripture, such as the creation account of Genesis 1 and 2. Convention members who held to conservative doctrinal views saw the danger and prepared a statement in 1979 that emphasized the need for doctrinal unity within functional diversity.


Starting in the 1980s, there has been a conservative “takeover” or resurgence within the leadership of the convention. In 1995 the convention approved a resolution renouncing its racist past and apologizing for its past defense of slavery. In 2000 the Baptist Faith and Message was revised to reflect support for a male-only pastorate and instructing women to exhibit loving submission to their husbands. As a result of these and other conservative decisions, there have been a number of churches and groups that have separated and formed their own associations or joined other associations. In 2004 the SBC removed itself from the Baptist World Alliance, which it said had become too liberal.

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/Southern-Baptist-Convention.html
Another article that might be of interest to you says this, in part:

The American Baptist Church traces its history in the U.S. to the founding of the first Baptist church in America by Roger Williams in Rhode Island in 1638. Through the years various Baptist associations were formed in the Colonies and the States to advance the cause of education and missions. In 1814 the Triennial Convention, a national Baptist body, was formed and later named the American Baptist Foreign Mission Society. Slavery became an issue in the church in the years leading up to the American Civil War. In 1845 the American Baptist Foreign Mission Society ruled it would no longer appoint missionaries who were slaveholders. That same year the American Baptist Home Mission Society divided into separate northern and southern conventions. The group of churches in the South became the Southern Baptist Convention. In 1907 the Northern Baptist Convention was organized, and in 1950 their name was changed to the American Baptist Convention. The name changed again in 1972 to American Baptist Churches USA.

Source: https://www.gotquestions.org/American-Baptist-Church.html

I would recommend The Baptist Heritage, Four Centuries Of Baptist Witness by H. Leon McBeth. It is a comprehensive history so you better like to read, at page 340 I'm only nearly half way through. Your question can be answered just reading chapters 1-4, 11 and 15 though.
